# Flash: embed textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz into my swf

Tags: flash

How can I embed an `textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz`  into my swf file?
This swz is a bit explained at http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=242293

It is additional part of flash runtime, which is needed to show my swf file.
But now, I must to put this textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz at the same dir as my swf. 
Can I aggregate swz and swf in a single, playable (with flash plugin) file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the swc from here if it's not already saved on your machine... http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/textlayout.html

You can then merge the swc into your swf by changing the "Default Linkage" to "Merged into code" http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSb03e830bd6f770ee-4b0db644124bbdb363d-8000.html#WSb03e830bd6f770ee72b69dc71257a25aa72-8000

Answer (score 1):

RSL mechanism, which is a Flex feature, use SWZ file. So you can't use SWZ in flash applications.

What you need is a SWC file.